Javascript <div>.innerHTML seems to block
I have this page. Basically, it runs two Alpha-beta pruning -based AI bots in the game of Connect Four. The problem I am experiencing is that I get the entire output after the game is over even if I do add more progress text to the holder <div> via innerHTML while the game is going.
How can make it to spit the intermediate state text to the <div>...</div> holding the output?
PS. If you decide to run the above page, it may take around 20 seconds to finish.
The culprit code
let text = "";
const output = document.getElementById('output-text-div');
const heuristicFunction = ...;
const engine = ...;
const depth = 8;

let state = new ConnectFourBoard();
text += state.toString() + "<br/>";

function millis() {
  return new Date().valueOf();
}

let totalDurationX = 0;
let totalDurationO = 0;

while (true) {
  text += "X's turn:<br/>";

  let ta = millis();
  state = engine.search(state, depth, X);
  let tb = millis();

  totalDurationX += tb - ta;

  text += state.toString();
  text += "<br/>";
  text += "X AI duration: " + (tb - ta) + " milliseconds.<br/>";
  output.innerHTML = text;

  if (state.isTie()) {
    text += "RESULT: It's a tie.<br/>";
    break;
  }

  if (state.isWinningFor(X)) {
    text += "RESULT: X won.<br/>";
    break;
  }

  text += "O's turn:<br/>";
  output.innerHTML = text;

  var i = output.height;

  ta = millis();
  state = engine.search(state, depth, O);
  tb = millis();
  output.innerHTML = text;

  totalDurationO += tb - ta;

  text += state.toString();
  text += "<br/>";
  text += "O AI duration: " + (tb - ta) + " milliseconds.<br/>";

  if (state.isTie()) {
    text += "RESULT: It's a tie.<br/>";
    break;
  }

  if (state.isWinningFor(O)) {
    text += "RESULT: O won.<br/>";
    break;
  }

  output.innerHTML = text;
  i = output.width;
}

text += "X AI total duration: " + totalDurationX + " milliseconds.<br/>";
text += "O AI total duration: " + totalDurationO + " milliseconds.<br/>";

output.innerHTML = text


Browsers don't update the view until they have to. If a script is still running, they wait until it's finished. You can break up your code into intervals to have the screen update more frequently.

@Pointy Oh hell duh... :/ Point right there!

@Pointy Could you illustrate how breaking up a script might seem in code? That would be a nice answer.

Well I've been thinking, and while breaking it up with timers would work, it might also work if you added code to query the DOM after changing it, like asking for the height of your <div>. I'm not sure exactly what would do it, but if your code asks for some metric about the DOM, the browser has no choice but to render.

It'll be better to show a sample code to demonstrate the problem.

@ChibuezeOpata Added the code. If it's too large, tell me and I will prune it.

Your example is not particularly complete (i.e. the engine, heuristicFunction and Connect24Board are missing) but you can achieve an incremental display by break it down with requestAnimationFrame and setTimeout, something like below
function gameLoop()
 //initialize engine, connectBoard, base content etc
 setTimeout(() => {
        let ta = millis();
        state = engine.search(state, depth, O);
        let tb = millis();

        totalDurationO += tb - ta;

        text += state.toString();
        text += "<br/>";
        text += "O AI duration: " + (tb - ta) + " milliseconds.<br/>";
        output.innerHTML = text;

        if (state.isTie()) {
            text += "RESULT: It's a tie.<br/>";
            output.innerHTML = text;
            return;
        }
        //etc
        // use requestAnimationFrame for recursive updates
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
   }, 0);
}


Thanks for the answer. I will try it tomorrow. If it works, a like and accept is yours.
